# How to change the default branch to push in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, branch

I like creating named branches in Mercurial to deal with features that might take a while to code, so when I push I do a `hg push -r default` to ensure I'm only pushing changes to the default branch. However, it is a pain to have to remember `-r default` every time I do do a push or outgoing command.

So I tried fix this by adding this config to my ~/.hgrc:

```
[defaults]
push = push -r default
outgoing = outgoing -r default
```

The problem is, those config lines are not really defaults, they are aliases. They work as intended until I try to do a `hg push -r <some revision>`. And the "default" I've setup just obliterates the revision I passed in. (I see that [defaults are deprecated](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#defaults), but aliases have the same problem).

I tried looking around, but I can't find anything that will allow me to set a default branch to push AND allow me to override it when necessary. Anyone know of something else I could do?

ps: I do realize that I could have separate clones for each branch, but I would rather not do that. It's annoying to have to switch directories, particularly when you have shared configuration or editor workspaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with pure mercurial, short of having a clone with only that branch in it (which I was was about to suggest until you said it wasn't your cup of tea).  If it's really killing you you can create a tiny wrapper script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
HG=/full/path/to/hg # executable
if echo $* | grep -P -q -- 'push.*\s-r($|\s)' ; then
   $HG $*
else
   $HG $* -r default
fi
```

name it 'hg' and put it earlier in your path.

Comment: I had to modify the script some to make it not add "-r default" to commands other than push and outgoing, but thanks very much for the push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Tortoise HG perhaps? Doing a full revert to an explicit branch name will cause Tortoise HG to remember the branch you're working on during subsequent commits. I'm not sure what metadata it gleans this from.

```
hg up -r {branchname}
```

e.g.

```
hg up -r dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Since normally you should push changesets in the current branch you are working, I modified the above answer made by ry4an-brase, to push current branch with a notice.

```
#!/bin/sh
HG=/usr/bin/hg # executable

if echo $* | grep -P -q -- 'push\s*$' ; then
    printf "\033[1;31mChanged to: hg push -r .\033[0m\n"
    $HG $* -r .
else
    $HG $*
fi
```